# Pandas transform csv into dict

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dictionary

I have a csv like this:

```
key,value
basico_uf_situacao_1,urb_cid_vila
basico_uf_situacao_2,nao_urb_cid_vila
basico_uf_situacao_3,urb_isolada
basico_uf_situacao_4,rur_ext_urb
basico_uf_situacao_5,rur_isol_povoado
basico_uf_situacao_6,rur_isol_nucleo
basico_uf_situacao_7,rur_isol_outros_aglo
basico_uf_situacao_8,rur_excl_rur
```

And I'm reading it like this:

```
index = pd.read_csv("./pdfs/indice.csv", delimiter=",")
```

How can I transform it into a dict which I can access like this:

In:

```
dict["basico_uf_situacao_1"]
```

Out:

```
urb_cid_vila
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Series.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
my_dict=df.set_index('key')['value'].to_dict() #set_index only if key not is the index
print(my_dict)
```

---

```
{'basico_uf_situacao_1': 'urb_cid_vila',
 'basico_uf_situacao_2': 'nao_urb_cid_vila',
 'basico_uf_situacao_3': 'urb_isolada',
 'basico_uf_situacao_4': 'rur_ext_urb',
 'basico_uf_situacao_5': 'rur_isol_povoado',
 'basico_uf_situacao_6': 'rur_isol_nucleo',
 'basico_uf_situacao_7': 'rur_isol_outros_aglo',
 'basico_uf_situacao_8': 'rur_excl_rur'}
```

---

```
my_dict['basico_uf_situacao_1'] 
#'urb_cid_vila'
```